# Is it possible to fetch Records from CoreStore using offset/paging?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, corestore

I want to implement paging kind of ui using UITableview so that once user is at last record while scrolling, I want to fetch next set of records from Local db using CoreStore.

Does [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) support this kind of feature while querying?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your persistent store, because fetchLimit is simply ignored when using SQLiteStore. That is a CoreData restriction (or bug, depends how you want to call it).

In CoreStore you can use tweak on the querychainbuilder, like

```
CoreStore.fetchAll(From<YourEntity>().tweak({ $0.fetchLimit = 50 }))
```

That modifies the NSFetchRequest that offers fetchLimit and fetchOffset.

So to solve the CoreData restriction you would need to do something else, such as pre-defining your paging using a page attribute and extend your where clause whenever your endless loading triggers.